# Android Menu Bar - Symmetrical Icons

Tags: java, android

I have a relative layout within another layout that represents a menu bar on the bottom of the screen. no i wand the four menu icons be symmetrically distributet on the menu bar.

here is my code so far. problem is i dont want to set absolute "dip" values. is there a way to somehow get the screenwith and devide it by four ?

---

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_height="80dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
<ImageButton
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:id="@+id/homeButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/homeicon"/>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/homeButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:src="@drawable/searchicon"/>
<ImageButton
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchButton"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:id="@+id/bookmarksButton"
    android:src="@drawable/bookmarksicon" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bookmarksButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:src="@drawable/settingsicon" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you mean..you could try using a LinearLayout as the parent Viewgroup and for each button set width to 0dip and layout_weight to 1; something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer" android:id="@+id/footer2"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FF707070">
        <ImageButton android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="70dip" android:id="@+id/homeButton"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:src="@drawable/homeicon" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/searchButton"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip" android:src="@drawable/searchicon" />
        <ImageButton android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="70dip" android:id="@+id/bookmarksButton"
            android:src="@drawable/bookmarksicon" />
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:src="@drawable/settingsicon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

That should work since the parent viewgroup (LinearLayout) has :

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

I hope this works.

Comment: Sorry for the late post. This certainly is the way to do it. Yet it didnt work for me. But i my layout was messed up. I fixed it. And voila! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's obvious that you don't understand what "dip" means. It means "Density Independent Pixels". This allows you to develop your layout for multiple devices very easily. So, if you develop a layout for a standard density device (like the Droid Pro) that will scale perfectly on other devices.

Here are some video tutorials by Motorola to help you understand this concept.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClrLNXLd5vs

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5yagMoiM-s

Comment: you didnt seem to understand my question. i am aware of what dip are but they wont allow me to distribute the buttons symmetrically so that all buttons take the same space (4 buttons = every button 1/4 of available screen width) on every device. this is only possible by declaring a "layout_weight".